# GOLD Parser comment grammar

Tags: grammar, bnf, dfa, gold-parser

I'm having some trouble with comment blocks in my grammar.  The syntax is fine, but Step 3 DFA scanner is complaining about the way I'm going about it.

The language I'm trying to parse looks like this:

{statement}{statement} etc.

Within each statement can be a couple of different types of comments:

```
{% This is a comment.
It can contain multiple lines
and continues until the statement end}

{statement  REM This is a comment.  
It can contain multiple lines  
and continues until the statement end}
```

This is a simplified grammar that displays the problem I'm running into:

```
"Start Symbol" = <Program>

{String Chars} = {Printable} + {HT} - ["\]
StringLiteral = '"' ( {String Chars} | '\' {Printable} )* '"'

Comment Start = '{%'
Comment End = '}'
Comment Block @= { Ending = Closed }  ! Eat the } and produce an empty statement
!Comment @= { Type = Noise }  !Implied by GOLD

Remark Start = 'REM'
Remark End = '}'
Remark Block @= { Ending = Open }  ! Don't eat the }, the statements expects it
Remark @= { Type = Noise }

<Program> ::= <Statements>
<Statements> ::= '{' <Statement> '}' <Statements> |  <>
<Statement> ::= StringLiteral
```

Step 3 is complaining about the } in <Statements> and the } for the End of the lexical group.

Anyone know how to accomplish what I need?

**[Edit]**
I got the REM portion working with the following:

```
{Remark Chars} = {Printable} + {WhiteSpace} - [}]
Remark = 'REM' {Remark Chars}* '}'
<Statements> ::= <Statements> '{' <Statement> '}'
              |  <Statements> '{' <Statement> <Remark Stmt>
              |  <>
<Remark Stmt> ::= Remark
```

This is actually ideal, since Remarks are not necessarily noise to me.

Still having issues with the comment lexical group.  I'll look at solving in the same way.

Comment: I would love to help but i dont know gold-parser, i use bison. I thought it would be a conflict like shift/reduce or reduce/reduce.  i dont see anything wrong. What does it exactly say? (maybe you shouldnt write as i wouldnt know how to fix it anyways) -edit- yeah i cant understand this. I dont see how remark or comment ties into the grammar. It looks like ATM only string litereals can be use and only in a statement block

Comment: The exact error is: 

DFA State 12: Cannot distinguish between: } } 

The conflict is caused when two or more terminal definitions can accept the same text.

Comment: hmm, i'm thinking about shift/reduce problems in bison. Could it be complaing bc when it says `{ stringliterForStatement }` <-- could `}` be confused for ending statement (excepting a statement afterwards) or ending a remark/comment? in bison you get this error bc it doesnt know if it should reduce and shifting would do more work. However its a warning and its up to the programmer to choose if he wants to change the rules or allow it. Also it can cause problems when 2 paths can end completely and it doesnt know which to choose

Comment: Yeah, I'd say it's most likely a conflict.  The question is, how do I work around it given the constraints.  The lexical group system in GOLD seems to allow for a Ending symbol that isn't consumed ( Ending = Open ), but doesn't seem to be ok with the conflict presented here.

Comment: i dont know. In bison i just live it with. At first i had about 6conflicts, now i have 32. All i understood and choose to live with. The last time i used gold parser i tried writing `var '=' var` as a rule along with +-*/. It flipped out and gave me conflicts :(. So i stopped using it. In bison i can get rid of it by saying %left '+' and %right '=' which tells it which side to do first to avoid a conflict like `a = b = c + d + e` (it does c+d,e,b,a)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think capturing the REM comment with a lexical group is possible.

I think you need to define a new terminal like this:

```
Remark = 'REM' ({Printable} - '}')*
```

This however means, that you need to be able to handle this new terminal in your productions...

Eg.
From:

```
<CurlyStatement> ::= '{' <Statement> '}'
```

To:

```
<CurlyStatement> ::= '{' <Statement> '}'
                   | '{' <Statement> Remark '}'
```

I have'nt checked the syntax in the above examples, but I hope you get my idear

Comment: I'm playing around with this, but I seem to be running into roadblocks from every direction.  The terminal needs to accept whitespace, otherwise the parser fails on the first space in the remark, but adding the whitespace character set causes parsing to completely fail for everything.  If I could get this working, that would be great, but that still leaves the {% comment} problem.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I was able to get that part working.  I'll add that solution to my original question.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what your problem is in the first case ..What is the problem with using your lexical group for the {% ... } comment ? Isn´t this just noise ? Otherwise the terminal-solution should be applicable in this case as well.

Comment: I just got an email from Devin Cook (GOLD author) saying that it's a bug and he'll get an update out.  So I'll wait and see on that one.